# Magento - Simple Configurable Products Extension

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I'm using the Magento SCP extension to change various details on the product page when selecting an option in the configurable product.

I need to extend the functionality so that I can change the description, image etc when clicking on a thumbnail image instead of changing the  list options.

As far as I can tell, the function that deals with the changing of product description etc is:

```
Product.Config.prototype.reloadPrice
```

I'm not sure how I can run this when I click on a thumbnail, what information do I need to pass to the function to run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end.

When changing the dropdown values from clicking on an image elsewhere in the page I need to run the following code:

```
spConfig.configureElement(element)
```

Where (element) is the Dropdown's ID which I stored in a VAR further up the page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site I am working on, this is using bundle products.  But I am just looking to get an idea of what you are trying to do..

Click on the individual products to see them load below your selection

Let me know if this is what you are looking to do and I can help guide you 
[Site Example](http://swarming.nationalcycle.com/vstream-mt.html)

The site I am demonstrating is using a custom route I load via Ajax.